# How can I make this kind of table in Latex?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

[image]

I want to make this kind of table.

Comment: As the guy who edited the tag suggest, look up `multirow` and `multicolumn`

Comment: It is possible through a judicious use of the  `\multicolumn` command and the package `multirow.sty`.  See also [Excel2LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/), but I've never used it....

Comment: @user54872: If the marked duplicate does not answer your question, please provide us with more detail as to *why* it doesn't. Include in this update a reference to what you have tried. There are multiple examples of random table generations on this site...